# Flutter - Boolean value keeps reseting after Navigator.pop() gets called

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class called `Counter`,

```
   int value1;
    bool isValueValid;
    
          class Counter {
            void init(Data data) {
            if(data == null) {
            value1 = 0;
            isValueValid = true;
            }
          }
     }
```

The method `init()` of Counter is called in the `initState()` of my app,

```
void initState() {
Counter().init(widget.data);
super.initState();
}
```

The value of `value1` or `isValueValid` gets set to `0` and `false` respectively on the `onTap()` of the `MaterialButton`, however when I navigate to another page and then come back to the same page using `Navigator.pop()`, the value of `isValueValid` becomes true again even though it should be false. My method `Counter().init` is not called anywhere else my app.

```
      MaterialButton(
        height: 40,
        onPressed: () {
        if(value1 >= 1 || isValueValid) {
        print('loop entered');
        value1 = 0;
        isValueValid = false;
          setState(() {} 
// I need to call `setState` to change the color of a `Container` which is dependent on the bool `isValueValid`
        }
        });
```

Comment: Where is `isValueValid` stored?

Comment: isValueValid is a global variable defined in my Home

Comment: Is the `Counter()` constructor called anywhere else in your app even if the `init` method is not?

Comment: So I was calling Counte().init in another onTap() and due to a problem in my if else, it triggered it on the Navigator.push() instead of pop(). It was a silly mistake! Thanks for your help